# EL model attribute scope, param vs global

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, servlets, parameters, el

In Spring MVC, what dictates if the model attribute is exposed at `global scope`

`${foo}`

or as a member of param

`${param.foo}`

It seems arbitrary decision, as `@ModelAttribute` ends up as a member of `param`, but attribute added programmatically to `model` is exposed at global namespace. Same thing with `RedirectAttributes`, `addAttribute()` goes under `param`, but `addFlashAttribute()` goes `global`.

Is there some logic or explanation for this behavior?

Comment: I don't do Spring, but in standard JSP EL, the `${param}` represents `request.getParameterMap()`. So, `${param.foo}` basically returns `request.getParameterMap().get("foo")` alas `request.getParameter("foo")`. Perhaps this should clarify things.

Comment: By the way, you initially called those `${}` things JSTL instead of EL. JSTL is just an user of EL. I fixed the terminology in the question. To learn the difference between both, head to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info